# How to calculate exact (minutes) from mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to calculate time in (minutes) between two datetime data

it_helpdesk-table

```
request_Date                xetr                   CALCULATE_TIME (I want)
01/01/2017 10:20 AM         01/01/2017 10:40 PM     20 MINUTES
01/01/2017 10:20 AM         01/01/2017 12:20 AM     120  MINUTES
```

I USE THIS CODE BUT GET WRONG O/P

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,Request_Date, Xetr) as WH
```

Comment: What is wrong about `timestampdiff()`?

Answer (score 1):

Why not [timediff()](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/timediff.php) and [time_to_sec()](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/time_to_sec.php)?

```
select time_to_sec(timediff(Request_Date, Xetr))/60 as WH
```